# Greatest common divisors of a family of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

For $n\geq 2$, consider the polynomial $f_n(x):=x^n-(x-1)^n-1$.

Let $m\neq n$, and let $d=d(m,n):=gcd(f_n,f_m)$. Via extensive computer calculations, I am convinced that the following must hold:

When either $m$ or $n$ (or both) is even $d=x-1$
If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then $=x(x-1)$ when $3$ divides $m$ or $n$ (or both). If $(m,n)\equiv (1,1)\pmod 6$, then $d=(x^2-x+1)^2x(x-1)$; if $(m,n)\equiv (-1-1)\pmod 6$, then $d=(x^2-x+1)x(x-1)$, and if $(m,n)\equiv (\pm 1, \mp 1)\pmod 6$ then $d=(x^2-x+1)(x-1)$.

I might have switched some of the answers, but the point is that there is periodicity modulo $6$.

So far I could only show that $d$ is a multiple of what I claim to be the correct answer.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that if $n=p^r,m=p^s$ for some prime $p$, then WLOG $r<s$ (since $n\neq m$) and in that case there is an extra factor of $p$. For example
$$
\gcd(f_5,f_{25}) = 5 (-1 + x) x (1 - x + x^2)
$$

Comment: Yes, if you want to do it over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ you will need to refine my answer. I was implicitly working over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.